# Criando mapa personalizado com vários pontos, gerenciáveis pelo Wordpress

Tags: jquery, json, wordpress, google-maps, rest

Vocês sabem como gerar um arquivo json no wordpress?.

Estou tentando criar um mapa onde os pontos personalizados são gerenciáveis pelo Wordpress, estou usando o plugin [ACF Advanced Custom Fields](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/), onde você cria um campo personalizado do tipo mapa e consegue imprimir, se quiser, a longitude e latitude.

Eu estava me baseando por esse tutorial [Criando um mapa com pontos customizados no Google Maps](http://www.princiweb.com.br/blog/programacao/google-apis/google-maps-api-v3-criando-um-mapa-personalizado.html), o que eu não sei é gerar o arquivo json contendo somente essas informações que eu quero, eu vi que tem uma coisa chamada [API REST](https://tableless.com.br/rest-json-wp-api-e-o-futuro-do-wordpress/), que gera o json pela url.

A pergunta é como filtrar isso. Alguém aí conseguiu entender o que eu preciso e conseguiria me ajudar?

**UPDATE**
Eu consegui fazer,inclusive resolvi o problema de agrupamento depontos proxímos, se por acaso alguém tiver um problema assim, me envie um email que eu envio todo o projeto já pronto.

E-Mail: [redact]

Comment: Eu sugeriria que fizesse um laço pra ler os valores dos campos e os escreveria em JSON no arquivo que seria lido conforme o tutorial. Já a API REST que vc citou é outra coisa. É um plugin capaz de tornar o WP em uma API com os dados existentes na ferramenta. Caso seja útil de alguma forma, existe o plugin [ACF to REST](https://wordpress.org/plugins/acf-to-rest-api/) que pega os dados dos seus custom fields e os disponibiliza a partir do [WP REST API](https://wordpress.org/plugins/rest-api/)

Comment: Sou meio leigo rss, mas pelo que eu entendi dessa forma que vc falou isso seria estático, já que eu precisaria por os valores na mão, e esses valores deve vim da base de dados,

Comment: Dinâmicamente, mesmo. Dá uma olhada aqui na documentação do [ACF](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/code-examples/). Vc pega do banco os valores dos campos e manipula-os com o php para criar o arquivo com o conteúdo JSON. Existe também [esse plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/multiple-location-google-map/) que pode resolver o seu problema de uma maneira mais simples.